# Using Dynamic Select query in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am using Hibernate 4.2 .
I want my select query return dynamic columns using same entity class.
E.g
Case 1:-

```
session.createSQLQuery("select id , name from  customer").addEntity(Customer.class).list();
```

Case 2:-

```
session.createSQLQuery("select id , name,address from customer").addEntity(Customer.class).list();
```

this is not possible , it gives error for case 1.

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
 at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
 at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
 at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2223)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
```

I want to use same ORM for both queries.

Comment: So what's the question here?

Comment: so what do you want to say? i are telling us that you are using Hibernate 4.2 or this is question?

Comment: The rest of the stack trace (that you chose not to post) should explain what is wrong with the query. That said, omitting fields will most likely not bring any significant performance gain, but will break the invariants of the Customer class. Just use HQL: `select c from Customer c`.